# Display Current Date Time in TextBox using MaskedEditExtender in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, asp.net-ajax

I try to display current DateTime in txtDateTime
How to display current datetime or custom date time in the textbox using Maked Edit Extender Ajax tool kit in asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDateTime" ValidationGroup="ModalPopup"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:CalendarExtender runat="server"
                                                TargetControlID="txtDateTime"
                                                PopupPosition="TopRight" 
                                                Format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm">
                                            </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                            <asp:MaskedEditExtender runat="server"
                                                ID="meeDateTime"
                                                TargetControlID="txtDateTime"
                                                Mask="99/99/9999 99:99"
                                                MaskType="DateTime"
                                                UserDateFormat= "DayMonthYear"
                                                UserTimeFormat="TwentyFourHour"
                                                CultureDateFormat="DMY"
                                                CultureDatePlaceholder="/"           CultureTimePlaceholder=":">
                                            </asp:MaskedEditExtender>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//txtDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm);
//txtDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm);
txtDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

code Behind

Comment: In what format you want to dislpay the datetime..??

Answer (score 3):

You dont have to write code in `txtDateTime.Text` since you are using ajax control.

You have set `TargetControlID="txtDateTime"` so it will automaticali take the date in that text box.

If you want to take it in masked Edit extender, then:

```
 txtDateTime.Text =   String.Format("{0:t}", Now);
```

Depending on format you want to set date, you can edit String.Format.