# CalendarExtender doesn't work correctly in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, datetime, ajaxcontroltoolkit, datetime-format, calendarextender

I used CalendarExtender with TextBox in aspnet.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime" TextMode="DateTime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="txtDateTime" Format="G" Animated="True" PopupPosition="Right" 
FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

On Page_Load event I set current date and time to TextBox's value:

```
txtDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Then, CalendarExtender doesn't work correctly. The calendar frame become completely white. Are you help me, what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDateTime" ValidationGroup="ModalPopup"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:CalendarExtender runat="server"
                                            TargetControlID="txtDateTime"
                                            PopupPosition="TopRight" 
                                            Format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm">
                                        </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                        <asp:MaskedEditExtender runat="server"
                                            ID="meeDateTime"
                                            TargetControlID="txtDateTime"
                                            Mask="99/99/9999 99:99"
                                            MaskType="DateTime"
                                            UserDateFormat= "DayMonthYear"
                                            UserTimeFormat="TwentyFourHour"
                                            CultureDateFormat="DMY"
                                            CultureDatePlaceholder="/"           CultureTimePlaceholder=":">
                                        </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
```

On Page Load use This code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 txtDateTime.Text =   String.Format("{0:t}", Now);
}
```

Link below from stackoverflow
[Display Current Date Time in TextBox using MaskedEditExtender in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566184/display-current-date-time-in-textbox-using-maskededitextender-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a MaskedExtender too.

`<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxID" runat="server"/>`

`<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskData" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBoxID" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date"/>`

Then you can use the calendarExtender

`<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBoxID" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"/>`